# Calling a SUB from a Class from a namespace VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, class

I have a code but cant get it to work.
I have a .vb site with a namespace and a Class and a Sub.
Then on my index.aspx site i cant to call this sub
The 2 sites is in the root of my project, and the name of the project is CalendarWeek

My WeekController.vb is

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar
Imports System.Globalization

Namespace CalendarWeekController
    Public Class WeekShow

    Shared Sub Main()
        ' Gets the Calendar instance associated with a CultureInfo.
        Dim myCI As New CultureInfo("da-DK")
        Dim myCal As Calendar = myCI.Calendar

        ' Gets the DTFI properties required by GetWeekOfYear.
        Dim myCWR As CalendarWeekRule = myCI.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule
        Dim myFirstDOW As DayOfWeek = myCI.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek

        ' Displays the number of the current week relative to the beginning of the year.
        Console.WriteLine("The CalendarWeekRule used for the en-US culture is {0}.", myCWR)
        Console.WriteLine("The FirstDayOfWeek used for the en-US culture is {0}.", myFirstDOW)
        Console.WriteLine("Therefore, the current week is Week {0} of the current year.", myCal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, myCWR, myFirstDOW))

        ' Displays the total number of weeks in the current year.
        Dim LastDay = New System.DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31)
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} weeks in the current year ({1}).", myCal.GetWeekOfYear(LastDay, myCWR, myFirstDOW), LastDay.Year)
    End Sub 'Main 


End Class
```

End Namespace

And My index.aspx is

```
    <%@ Import Namespace="CalendarWeekController" %>
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="index.aspx.vb" Inherits="" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <%  
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Me.IsPostBack = False Then
        Call WeekShow(Sub Main) 

        End If
    End Sub

%>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i get this error when running the site.
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'CalendarWeek.CalendarWeekController'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Import Namespace="CalendarWeekController" %>
Line 2:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="CalendarWeek.CalendarWeekController" %>
Line 3:  
Line 4:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call shared subs with `Classname.Subname`.
In your case:

```
WeekShow.Main()
```

Comment: hi if i changes that code it almost work, i get this error now:
Statement cannot appear within a method body. End of method assumed. And this one: 'End Sub' must be preceded by a matching 'Sub'.

Comment: Why don't you use the Codebehind file? Are you using Visual Studio?
If not, have a look at this link: http://www.asp101.com/articles/john/codebehindnovs/default.asp
But Visual Studio Express is fo free: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-Basic
Have a look at the page-model, inparticular the codebehind part: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb.aspx